# Looking for verses for my Hebrew name to use during the shmona esrei

Tags: names

I'm looking for verses for my Hebrew name Yehudah Yitzchuk to use during the shmona esrei. Is there more than one to choose from?   Is there a link to the source(s)?

Comment: Hello user9651 and welcome to m.y! What are you planning to use them for? There are many possible verses that include/correspond to/relate to your names, which can probably be narrowed down greatly depending on your intentions. Is it for prayer? Research? Poetry?

Comment: Check the back of the standard Hebrew-English ArtScroll Siddur.  Page 960 in the Ashkenaz seems to ring a bell with me for this (I used to use it a lot).

Answer (score 1):

See [this page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20312&st=&pgnum=390) Both Yehuda and Yitzhak are listed. Many Siddurim such as Art Scroll have a list of verses for all Hebrew names. See the rules in the next paragraph.

Technically, any verse that starts with the 1st letter of your Hebrew name and ends with the last letter of your Hebrew name is valid. There may be more than one verse fitting that criteria for certain names. However, personally, I don't have the time to manually hunt for them. Perhaps there is a computer program that can detect these?

Comment: "technically...valid" I didnt think that any technical law was involved, or that some verses are valid or invalid. I thought that this was just an optional (possibly Sabbatean practice).

Comment: @mevaqesh By "technically" I mean "according to the rules of how it's done", as I had described. I wasn't implying that there is any halacha to recite the verse or halachic rules that determine this. It is a minhag, but I don't know its source.

Comment: I knew what you meant, I was just making a point.

Comment: @DanF, here are the sources for the custom http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2451435/jewish/Names-Verses-and-Flaming-Hot-Rods.htm . It is recorded before Shabbtai Tzvi was born. The only accusation is on the specific choice of location on where to say it (see footnote 10 there).